# Android Service - stop the service from settings App

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have developed a music player application,which has a service(AudioPlayerService) which will be running in the background.Service will be started when play button is pressed. It will run in the background even though application goes to background.

Playback can be stopped by bringing the app to foreground and press the stop button, which makes the music to stop and stops the AudioPlayerService too. everything works fine.

Otherway i can use the **Force Stop** from Settings app (*Settions->Application->Downloaded->Select the App->Press Force Stop Button*).
I am able to stop the application and music also stopped playing.

But If i use **Stop** button from Settings App (*Settings->Applications->Running->Select the App -> Press Stop*), application is terminated and my app is removed from the running app list, but music is still playing in the background.

I am not sure why Running Tab Stop Button does not stop the music.

Any one help me if i need to handle anything in my service to class to stop the playback.

I am testing in Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.0.3

Thanks
Sasikumar JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the onDestroy override method of your service use your mediaplayer object to stop  the media from playing.

```
@Override
OnDestroy{
    mediaplyer.stop();
}
```